# Filter Logic for SF report

Tags: reporting, error-messages, filters

I keep receiving this error message when applying filters to my report.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using successive AND or OR you need to apply parenthesis to group the logic for it to understand. As it stands, it has no way of knowing if you mean:

- 1 being true AND one of 2 OR 3 OR 4. This with proper parenthesis would be `1 AND (2 OR 3 OR 4)`

vs.

- 1 AND 2 being true or one of either 3 or 4. This with proper parenthesis would be `(1 AND 2) OR (3 OR 4)`